# TimePickerDialog with Neutral button

Tags: android, android-timepicker, dialog-preference

I have a TimePickerDialog preference with a "TimePreference" class which extends DialogPreference:

```
public class TimePreference extends DialogPreference{
...
private TimePicker picker=null;

...
public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(ctxt, attrs);
    setPositiveButtonText(android.R.string.ok);
    setNegativeButtonText(android.R.string.cancel);
}

@Override
protected View onCreateDialogView(){
    picker=new TimePicker(getContext());
    return(picker);
}
...
}
```

I would like to add a third button, which will set the preference to the current time and close the dialog, like this:

[image]

The question is, is there some way of doing this using TimePickers or should I make a custom AlertDialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your answers! I will show you how I finally managed it, just in case someone wants to do the same.

First, I have a layout file good_timedialog.xml which looks like I wanted:
[image: TimePicker with Positive, neutral and negative buttons]

Then I have a TimePreference class:

```
public class TimePreference extends DialogPreference{
    private final static String lTag="CustomTimeDialog";
    private TimePicker picker;
    protected TimeObj lastTime;

public TimePreference(Context ctxt,AttributeSet atrs) {
    super(ctxt,atrs);
    setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.good_timedialog); // this loads the layout
    setPositiveButtonText("");
    setNegativeButtonText(""); // hide default buttons
    setDialogTitle(ctxt.getString(R.string.selectTimeTimePrefTitle));
}

@Override
protected void onBindDialogView(View v){
    super.onBindDialogView(v);

    v.findViewById(R.id.butCancel).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Log.d(lTag,"cancel clicked");
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });
    v.findViewById(R.id.butNow).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Log.d(lTag,"now clicked");
            saveToSP(true);
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });
    v.findViewById(R.id.butOK).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Log.d(lTag,"ok clicked");
            saveToSP(false);
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });

    picker = (TimePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    if (picker!=null) {
        picker.setCurrentHour(lastTime.hr);
        picker.setCurrentMinute(lastTime.min);
    } else { // if it is null
        Log.w(lTag,"var picker is null!");
    }

}

void saveToSP(boolean now){
    if (now) lastTime = new TimeObj(); // make it the current time
    else {
        lastTime.hr = picker.getCurrentHour();
        lastTime.min = picker.getCurrentMinute();
    }
    setSummary(lastTime.giveString()); // update Summary like hh:mm 16:28

    int time = lastTime.giveMinutes(); // 10:30am will be 630 minutes

    // save to sharedprefs
    if(callChangeListener(time)){ 
        persistInt(time);
        if(getEditor().commit()) Log.d(lTag,"Successfully saved changes");
        else Log.w(lTag,"Did NOT save changes");

    }
}
//... more ...
}
```

And at the perferences.xml file, I can use `<com.example.TimePreference android:key="test"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Dialog supports three buttons by default - positive, negative and cancel. You could rename them as per your wish and handle them accordingly.